# Arch Linux: not able to get to Nokia phone storage

Tags: arch-linux, storage, usb-device, mobile, phone

I have a Nokia 230 mobile (basic model).

[image]

I am using Arch Linux. I was able to connect mobile to my laptop using USB and was able to see the storage files using `pcmanfn` (file manager). I used to get notification when I connect to my laptop.

Recently I upgraded my Arch Linux. After that I can't get to see the files in my phone. No notification comes from `pcmanfm` (file manager).

I checked `dmesg`. When it connects, it says:

```
usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 35 using xhci_hcd
```

`lsusb` shows:

```
Bus 002 Device 035: ID 0421:06c6 Nokia Mobile Phones
```

`lsusb -vvv`

```
Bus 002 Device 035: ID 0421:06c6 Nokia Mobile Phones 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0421 Nokia Mobile Phones
  idProduct          0x06c6 
  bcdDevice            3.39
  iManufacturer           1 Nokia
  iProduct                2 Nokia 208 Dual SIM
  iSerial                 3 357911050027165
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           39
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass         6 Imaging
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Still Image Capture
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Picture Transfer Protocol (PIMA 15470)
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval              10
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

How to know what's the problem and get my files?